# Angular.JS — A Directive, inside a directive, inside a directive, inside a directive. Scope issues

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have some issues regarding scope in nested directives. I have two directives: column and nested-menu. Their structure can be something like:

- column

  - nested-menu
  - nested-menu

    - nested-menu
    - other content
  - nested-menu
  - other content
- column

  - other content

The column has a variable to which all the nested-menu's should react. I have tried to make this work in several ways that I found Googling, such as broadcasting events from the column directive (for some reason, the nested-menu's only saw the event when I broadcasted it from $rootScope), setting a directive controller in column and storing the variable there (I can read it, but I can't $watch it).

It's important that both directives have an isolated scope, as they're supposed to be reusable in several areas, and sometimes even nested in themselves.

I have made a simplified Plnkr of a base structure, that's not working.
http://plnkr.co/edit/1GP7SKacO777og8PysNF

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you want this to behave exactly. But here is a plunker that solves the two directives interacting with each other.

The `nested-menu` only expects `column` in its parent currently, But you could change it to expect another `nested-menu` in its parent if you wish.

Here is the working plunker. Hope this helps.

http://plnkr.co/edit/IAn9Ib8sSkQwKx6mpsm5?p=preview

Comment: Hi Ganaraj. This is very close to what I want, thanks a lot. I want it to behave this way because the nested-menu's behaviour depends on the column's state.

However, I also need to listen to the value in the nested-menu directive (not only in the view). Do you have any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: Ha, I managed to $watch the controller function: http://plnkr.co/edit/9nIhoObRLbkSyiwKCQri

I'm accepting your answer.

I made a simple test case in that plnkr, where a function works, but a simple variable doesn't. Do you know why?